# Is there a solution for pdf template in PHP?

Tags: php, pdf

I need to generate quotes in pdf format by PHP, with a template and dynamic values retrieved from database.

is it viable ?

Comment: Just a heads-up: creating PDFs with PHP is very fiddly. Adjusting dimensions, positioning... Just allow yourself time for tweaking ;)

Answer (score 7):

UPDATE: i see people upvoting this recently and wanted to add that [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf) might be a better option for most applications.

yes,  [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/) + [fpdi](http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/) worked for me

basically, you create your pdf template first, then load it into the new FPDI object and use FPDF functions to draw "over" the template - much like photoshop layers work.

```
$pdf = new FPDI(); 

$pdf->setSourceFile('template.pdf'); 
$tpl = $pdf->importPage(1); 
$pdf->addPage(); 
$pdf->useTemplate($tpl); <- template is imported

$pdf->setXY(10, 20);
$pdf->write(100, "Hi there"); <- write or draw something on the template

$pdf->output('newpdf.pdf', 'D'); <- ready, save or output your pdf
```

Comment: My team is using FPDF to some success, though I haven't coded against it yet.

Comment: Do you mean I need these two libs to create a customized pdf,or ...can you demonstrate ?

Comment: Last but no least,is it free?Seems not ..?

Comment: Good !
But I want the dynamic text be added like this way:`print("this is your product:%s",$name)`.Seems it's not the case in the demo.

Comment: No,in a photoshop manner,I don't think it can handle the overflow issue,I need it to wrap around instead of go out of view.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [DOMPDF](http://www.digitaljunkies.ca/dompdf/). It's very good & easy to use, and has got some very useful APIs. I have used it twice, and it really amazes me as to what not you can do.

Really, you can set multiple pages in the on-the-fly created PDF, with resized images acting as catalog products.

It has a very good Documentation, with examples shown. If you have any problems integrating it, feel free to post your question here, and the users will be proactive in answering your questions.

[DOMPDF](http://www.digitaljunkies.ca/dompdf/) is an awesome cool stuff. I think that it has also won some awards, for its sheer coding standard.
Check out yourself, for more!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford the licensing costs, [PDFLIB](http://pdflib.com/) has a nice templating system they call "blocks". You draw the blocks onto the source template in Acrobat, assign it a name, and then in the PHP code it's a simple matter of issuing a "fill this block with the following text/image/eps".

Once all the housekeeping code of opening the template/loading fonts/etc...is completed, the fill-in-the-blanks codes boils down to:

```
PDF_fill_textblock($pdf, $pagehandle, $blockname, "Text to insert", 'fitting method arguments');
PDF_fill_imageblock($pdf, $pagehandle, $blockname, $imagehandle, 'fitting method arguments');
PDF_fill_pdfblock($pdf, $pagehandle, $blockname, $pdfhandle, 'arguments here');
```